# С (GCC). Как исключить из сборки неиспользуемые функции?

Tags: c, gcc

В проекте есть пара *.c /* .h, в которой объявлены и определены несколько функций. При этом некоторые из них не используются. Но после компиляции, заглянув в листинг можно обнаружить там ассемблерный код этих самых неиспользуемых функций? Как исключить их из сборки? В моем случае память очень ограничена и хотелось бы оптимально ее расходовать. Да и вообще интересно. К тому же, не попадают же таким образом неиспользуемые ф-ии из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Это интерес практический или теоретический ?

Comment: Больше практический. Но и теоретическая сторона тоже интересна.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итак давайте разбираться, на этапе компиляции понятное дело что функции вряд-ли куда денутся, все они окажутся в объектном файле, следовательно все дело в сборке (linking).
Создадим пример:

```
/* Файл func1.c */
int FuncA (void) { return 1; } /* ни где не используется */
int FuncB (void) { return 2; } /* ни где не используется */

/* Файл func2.c */
int FuncC (void) { return 0; } /* используется в main() */

/* Файл func1.h */
int FuncA (void);
int FuncB (void);

/* Файл func2.h */
int FuncC (void);

/* Файл main.c */
#include "func1.h"
#include "func2.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) { return FuncC(); }
```

Теперь начинаем собирать:

```
gcc -o a.out main.c func1.c func2.c
```

Проверяем:

```
nm a.out | grep Func[ABC]
080483c4 T FuncA
080483ce T FuncB
080483d8 T FuncC
```

Ничего не получилось :-)
Делаем еще одну попытку:

```
gcc -c func1.c
gcc -c func2.c
gcc -o a.out main.c func1.o func2.o
```

Проверяем:

```
nm a.out | grep Func[ABC]
080483c4 T FuncA
080483ce T FuncB
080483d8 T FuncC
```

Опять все функции попали в выходной файл.
Применяем черную магию, а конкретно собираем библиотеку:

```
gcc -c func1.c
gcc -c func2.c
ar rcs lib.a func1.o func2.o
gcc -o main.c lib.a
```

Проверяем:

```
nm a.out | grep Func[ABC]
080483c4 T FuncC
```

Итак у нас получилось.

Отсюда вывод - разделяем исходняки на модули затем компилируем модули в объектные файлы, затем объектные файлы объединяем в библиотеку, а затем собираем основную программу с библиотеками подключатся только используемые **модули**

**UPDATE**

У gcc-шного линкера есть такая возможность как `-gc-sections` (garbage collect and discard unused sections), воспользоваться ею легко:

```
gcc -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -o a.out \
    main.c func1.c func2.c
nm a.out | grep Func[ABC]
080483c0 T FuncC
```

Но это не всегда приемлемо особенно когда это касается больших проектов. [Пример](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/11/21/garbage-collecting-sections-is-not-for-production)

Comment: Доходчиво. Спасибо за разяснения.

Comment: Это не интересно. Интересно было бы решить вопрос на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Согласен. Есть идеи?

Comment: Можно конечно воспользоваться опцией сборщика --gc-sections (garbage collect and discard unused sections) но тут из личного опыта возможны глюки особенно на развесистых проектах, полностью см:

    gcc -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -o a.out main.c func1.c func2.c

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вывод команды nm your.exe

Код будет помечен метками T и t (t это "внутренний" (static) код).

Часто несколько функций размещаются в одной единице компиляции (.c), которая (.o) линкуется с Вашим модулем либо непосредственно либо из библиотеки. Если Вы ссылаетесь на одну функцию из (.o), то остальные тоже прилинкуются.

IMHO исключить их нельзя.

Comment: Прилинкуются даже если они не static? Я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Или ровно наоборот?

Comment: Все функции из **одного** .c файла прилинкуются, даже если их **никто не вызывает**. При линковке из библиотеки этот .o подтянется, если есть вызов хотя бы одной функции в нем или обращение к внешней переменной, размещенной там.

Более того, если взять .o к адресам в котором вообще ниоткуда нет ссылок и передать его линкеру, то все его содержимое окажется в Вашем .exe

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вот написал такой тестик

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__ ((noinline)) static  int func_fff(int a) {
    puts ("OK");
    return a*2;
}

int main() {
    printf ("%d\n", 4);
#ifdef __COMP
    printf ("%d\n", func_fff (10));
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Параметры компиляции и выводы программы nm :

```
gcc test.c -c -o a.o

nm a.o | grep func_fff

t func_fff

gcc test.c -c -o a.o -O

nm a.o | grep func_fff

<nothing>

gcc test.c -c -o a.o -O -D__COMP

nm a.o | grep func_fff

t func_fff
```

Анализ ассемблерного кода также показывает, что во втором варианте никаких следов функции нет. Вывод: невключение невызываемой функции на этапе компиляции можно достичь, определяя ее как static и применяя оптимизацию компиляции (достаточно уровня О1).

P.S. Чтобы статическая функция включалась всегда, нужно ее объявлять с аттрибутом

```
__attribute__ ((used))
```

Comment: А если функция func_fff будет находится в другом файле?

Comment: Если функция объявляется как внешняя (т.е. без статик), то она обязательно будет включена. А без этого она не будет видна в другом модуле.

Comment: в этом случае поможет только способ, описаный @chernomyrdin?

Comment: Да, только обратите внимание, я уже писал: исключение происходит на этапе линковки библиотеки, а не на этапе компиляции. А случай на этапе компиляции я описал, как Вы и просили. Насколько я помню, в этом и состоял вопрос.

Comment: После первых ответов захотелось разобраться поглубже. Спасибо за помощь. Об обоих вариантах, думаю, стоит помнить. Пригодится.

Comment: И еще. Если в модуле статической библиотеки определены несколько функций, а в конечном файле вызывается только одна, то включены все равно будут все.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно повысить уровень оптимизации в той среде разработки, в которой пишете.
Сталкивался--помогало.
Пробуйте =)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не путаетет компиляцию и линковку?
На этапе компиляции обычно ничего не выбрасывается. А вот линковщик уже смотрим, что есть, а чего нет и просто не включает в результирующий файл. (Ну разве что включены всевозможные режимы для отладки, типа -ggdb).
Что бы убедиться, что результат такой, как нужно, рекомендую смотреть дизассемблером и генерировать карту функций. Для этого добавьте такой параметр -Wl,-Map=a.map к gcc. Формат файла a.map не хитрый, и может быть понят. Там будут перечислены все функции, их адреса, размеры и другая интересная информация, которая позволит Вам найти, где можно ещё немного соптимизировать.

Comment: Что-то все как-то сложно. Чаще всего помогает повышение уровня оптимизации при компиляции.

Comment: Может и путаю) Смотрел в файле *.lss. В map никакой особо информации о функциях. Или я что-то совсем не так понимаю. В lss функции в ассемблерном виде. Именно там я и вижу эти неиспользуемые функции. Режимы отладки не используются. Оптимизация -О3.

Comment: в lss Вы видите скомпилированные файлы. Нужно смотреть в результирующий файл.

Answer (score 0):

Нет способа убрать функцию с внешней линковкой, т.к. при компиляции модуля неизвестно какие из его символов будут использованы в других модулях. Поэтому единственный способ дать компилятору возможность удалить неиспользуемые функции - объявить их статическими.
Насчет стандартной библиотеки вы не правы - обычно стандартная библиотека линкуется динамически и используется несколькими приложениями системы, поэтому никакой код из нее не удаляется.