# GCC. Размер компилируемого файла прошивки

Tags: gcc

Первый раз столкнулся с GCC. Программу пишу для микроконтроллера в Eclipse на C++. Столкнулся с проблемой большого размера прошивки.
видел [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60801/%D0%A1-gcc-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/1203630#1203630) по опциям линкера, но --gc-sections уже стоит. Убрав ее, размер значительно возрастатет. Значит дело не в этом.
Толком еще ничего не успел написать, а размер уже приличный. Заметил, что при если убрать деструктор в абстрактном классе, то размер занимаемой флеш уменьшается примернео в 2 раза. Куда копать? В IAR такого не наблюдается.

Comment: Укажите платформу для которой собираете. Релиз или дебаг? IAR может более оптимльный код генерировать и просто иметь правильные ключи сборки

Comment: Флажок `-Os` стоит? Исключения отключены? (`-fno-exceptions`).

Comment: Для RISC-V, debug. Оптимизацию по размеру(-0s) ставил, уменьшение дает, но относительно немного. А где иключения посмотреть отключены или нет, или куда прописать не нашел?

Comment: Пишите на чистом Си

Comment: Хочу на С++ учиться. Нашел исключения (-fno-exceptions) отключены